# Как отобразить данные List<BsonDocument> в DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, mongodb, datagrid

У меня на wpf-форме есть элемент DataGrid.

Мне нужно отобразить данные MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument в на этой таблице.

```
var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(_mainQueryFilterSetter._currentCollection);
var filter = new BsonDocument();
var result = await collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();

dataGrid.ItemsSource = result; // создает только пустые строки в количестве документов в коллекции
```

DataGrid - стандартный элемент управления.

Значения в result есть, выводил циклом в MessageBox'ах, всё считывается.

Comment: DataGrid имеет какой то не стандартный вид или просто `<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" />`? И что в result? Есть ли там что отображать?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, в моем случае DataGrid стандартный. Значения в result есть,  для проверки выводил каждое циклом в MessageBox'ах, все данные имеются и считываются.

Comment: А как вы выводите циклом в MessageBox? Вообще по хорошему вам надо отделить базу от представления. База - это Модель, создайте некий класс, в нем метод с возвращающим result. Далее сделайте класс ViewModel одного объекта из базы (что там у вас, предположим птичка, добавляйте значит в этот класс необходимые свойства (имя, вид, возраст и др.), и еще одна ViewModel, основная, в ней сделайте свойство коллекции для привязки и метод заполнения этой коллекции из модели. Все, останется привязать все это к DataGrid через XAML. Если это вам лень, то попробуйте просто сделать свой тип и его заполняйте.

Answer (score 0):

Пользуйся не асинхронными методами при загрузке данных.

```
var collection = database.GetCollection(_mainQueryFilterSetter._currentCollection);
var filter = new BsonDocument(); 
var result = collection.Find(filter).ToList(); 
dataGrid.ItemsSource = result; // создает только
```